# Delete a specific relationship using py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Let's say we have 2 nodes, User and Post. The relationship, say upvote, can exist as (:User)-[UPVOTED]->(:Post)

If the following query results in a non-empty list, then I wish to delete the relationship:

```
        rel_list = list(graph.match(start_node=user, end_node=post, rel_type="UPVOTED")
        if len(rel_list) > 0:
            # delete the relationship from the graph
        else:
            # create the relationship
            rel = Relationship(user, "UPVOTED", post)
            graph.create_unique(rel)
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete relationships you should use the `separate` method: http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Transaction.separate.

You may want to take a look to this issue in GitHub for some discussion on that: https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/508

Regards,

Comment: I get this error:
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'separate'

Comment: That's because `separate` is a method of the `Transaction` object not `Graph`. You need to open a transaction with `tx=graph.begin()` and then run `tx.separate(your_relationship)` and finally commit with `tx.commit()`

Comment: But then, again it raises the error that 'Graph' object has no attribute 'begin'. That is a bit strange.

Comment: It happens to be that `graph.cypher.begin()` creates a transaction, however, it has no attribute called `separate`.

Comment: I see that you're also posting in [GitHub](https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/508) so I guess it doesn't make sense to continue here.

Comment: Yep! There were issues with version. The solution you suggested is v3 specific. I'm on v2. Will keep a track on the issue raised there. Thanks, anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, hope this helps others as well.

```
    rel_list = list(graph.match(start_node=user, end_node=post, rel_type="UPVOTED")
    if len(rel_list) > 0:
        # delete the relationship from the graph
        # fetch the ID of the relationship -> rel_id
        query = '''
        MATCH (a:NeoZotr)-[r:LIKED]->(b:NeoZot)
        WHERE ID(r) = {x}
        DELETE r
        '''
        graph.cypher.execute(query,x=rel_id)
    else:
        # create the relationship
        rel = Relationship(user, "UPVOTED", post)
        graph.create_unique(rel)
```

If you end up with TypeError (as was in my case), it might be possible that rel_id that you fetched was in unicode style. Pass int(rel_id) in  that case.